# Sed: Insert text before a random text

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I am having problems using sed to change this:

```
script_summary("Short random text");
script_id(@12345);
```

Into this:

```
script_tag(name:"text", value:"Short random text");
script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.@12345");
```

Could you please, point me out in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

Using 2 iterations. Testing it:

```
echo 'script_summary("Short random text");' | sed -e 's/script_summary("\(.*\)");/script_tag(name:"text", value:"\1");/'
echo 'script_id(@12345);' | sed -e 's/script_id(\(@[0-9]\+\));/script_oid("1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.\1");/'
```

So you may want to use it with 

`sed -i -e <regex1> <file>
sed -i -e <regex2> <file>`

or

`cat <file> | sed -e <regex1> | sed -e <regex2>`

depends on how big the files is, and what you want to do with it.